# Is there any benefit to sticking with the same color,  Pokémon Black > Black 2 and Pokémon White > White 2? 

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

Since this is the first time a Pokémon game has had a direct sequel, is there any advantage to getting the same color sequel instead of the opposite game?

Or should this just be treated like any other new Pokémon game, and just pick one?

Comment: At this point, this is speculation. We likely won't know anything until the games come out. As such, this is off-topic according to our FAQ. That said, this is a very interesting question and one that should certainly be asked once the games do come out and answers are no longer speculative.

Comment: @QAtash The games have been released in Japan (June 23, 2011 Japan Release Date) - but if we would want to wait for an American release date I can understand that. I just thought some importers would know.

Comment: @DylanYaga my apologies

Comment: @DylanYaga Ah, I didn't check the Japanese release date. Completely on topic then. +1 for it being very a very interesting one too :)

Comment: @QAtash Actually, the release date was June 23, 2012 in Japan, not 2011. http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Black_and_White_Versions_2

Comment: @Hunger Yes, 2012 - still not used to typing that yet...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The sequel is designed so that if you had the old Black (Reshiram) and get Black 2, you will get the same exclusives (not excluding the new non-Unova Pokemon) as the old Black with the exception of getting Zekrom instead of Reshiram and vice versa for White and White 2 (Reshiram instead of Zekrom).

In other words if you get the same color, you will be able to get the opposite legendary and have the same exclusives, but if you get the different color you'll get the same legendary as your other game, but different exclusives.

### Black 2 Exclusives

- Magmar
- Sudowoodo
- Heracross
- Magby
- Plusle
- Volbeat
- Spoink
- Grumpig
- Registeel*
- Latios
- Buneary
- Lopunny
- Bonsly
- Magmortar<sup>+</sup>
- Cottonee<sup>+</sup>
- Whimsicott
- Gothita
- Gothorita
- Gothitelle
- Vullaby
- Mandibuzz
- Zekrom
- Black Kyurem

### White 2 Exclusives

- Mr. Mime
- Electabuzz
- Pinsir
- Elekid
- Skitty
- Delcatty
- Minun
- Illumise
- Numel
- Camerupt
- Regice*
- Latias
- Mime Jr.
- Electivire
- Petilil<sup>+</sup>
- Lilligant<sup>+</sup>
- Solosis
- Duosion
- Reuniclus
- Rufflet
- Braviary
- Reshiram
- White Kyurem

*Obtainable in both versions via [Unova Link](http://www.serebii.net/black2white2/unovalink.shtml)
<sup>+</sup>Obtainable in the opposite version via in-game trade.

Certain areas will have [aesthetic changes](http://www.serebii.net/black2white2/versionarea.shtml) between the two versions, such as Route 4, the cave the connects Yamaji Town and Undella Town, and Opelucid City.

[Fes missions](http://www.serebii.net/black2white2/fesmission.shtml) will differ between the two versions and [Join Avenue](http://www.serebii.net/black2white2/joinavenue.shtml) will sell different items depending on the version.

Although Black City and White Forest are exclusive to their respective versions, you can use Unova Link to switch between the two.

Answer (score 2):

If this game is similar to the Japanese release then yes there is a benefit, because White will have Reshiram instead of Zekrom, and black will have Zekrom instead of Reshiram, so you will have both legendarys if you trade over your old legendary.

Hope this helped!